# List of attached USB devices using Java

Tags: java, usb

I am writing a Java application to get the list of all  USB devices attached to the computer, can any one help me please is this possible. If there is possibility please help me.

Comment: There is at least one USB library out on the Internet, I'd suggest trying to goggle around a bit and see what you find and try them